# Changing angle of text in pie chart with respect to radius

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, pie-chart

I have one question about placing text in pie chart. Let's have a code following.

```
library(ggplot2)
pie_chart=function(vec){
  if (class(vec)=='numeric'){vec<-as.character(vec)
  vec<-print(paste('var',vec))
  }
  #creating data frame : variables and number of their occurrences
  df<-data.frame(table(vec))
  colnames(df)[1]<-'group'
  #creating bar plot first
  bp<- ggplot(df, aes(x="", y=Freq, fill=group))+
    geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity")
  blank_theme <- theme_minimal()+
    theme(
      axis.title.x = element_blank(),
      axis.title.y = element_blank(),
      panel.border = element_blank(),
      panel.grid=element_blank(),
      axis.ticks = element_blank(),
      plot.title=element_text(size=14, face="bold")
    )
  #adding polar coordinates to make a circle
  pie <- bp + coord_polar("y", start=0)
  pie + scale_fill_brewer("Characteristic") + blank_theme +
    theme(axis.text.x=element_blank())+
    geom_text(aes(y = rev(Freq)/2 + c(0, cumsum(rev(Freq))[-length(Freq)]),
                  label = print(paste0(rev(Freq),'(',percent(rev(Freq)/(sum(Freq))),')'))), size=5)
  
}



pie_chart(c(rep(1,40),rep(2,30),rep(3,60),rep(4,50)))
```

[image]

And as you can see it look's like above. For each piece of pie, the text is horizontal. Is there any way how can we change it ? Let's have a text in the middle of lines which limits piece of pie. I.e. I want to have text placed like lines in the picture below.

[image]

Do you have any idea how to do it ?

Thank's in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an angle variable for a pie, just as with the position variable and then use this in geom_text to set the angle relative to 360 degrees in the circle.

E.g. if we add this to the example from https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/piechart-ggplot2.html it looks like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Create Data
data <- data.frame(
  group=LETTERS[1:5],
  value=c(13,7,9,21,2)
)

# Compute the position of labels
data <- 
  data %>% 
  arrange(desc(group)) %>%
  mutate(prop = value / sum(data$value) *100) %>%
  mutate(ypos = cumsum(prop)- 0.5*prop) %>% 
  mutate(yang = 90-(ypos/100*360))  # Create an angle variable relative to the text position

# Basic piechart
ggplot(data, aes(x="", y=prop, fill=group)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1, color="white") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) +
  theme_void() + 
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  geom_text(aes(y = ypos, label = group, angle = yang), color = "white", size=6) # add angle
```

Comment: Small error above, it's 360 not 365 degrees :)